# Exporting AUth2.0 bearer token with postman collection file does NOT work when executed using newman on cmd

Tags: api, rest, postman, imgur

Below are the steps

1. Add bearer token env variable, as shown below
   [image]
2. Add bearer token to the header on Main collection tab, and the request
   as shown below
   [image]
   [image]
3. And now manually check what happens when we run - **Get comments** request, use the 'inherit auth from parent' option - it shows 200 OK, and returns the comments as shown below

[image]

4. Now export both env variables & collection file as shown below
   [image]
   [image]
5. Run the files on cmd with newman as shown below
   [image]
6. Check the result of the 'Get Comments' request
   [image]

**Expected:** 200 OK status
**Actual** : 401 Unauthorized stauts

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: I don't see step add Bearer token to Header (somewhere between step 1 and 2)

Comment: Cool, i have added the step now  , but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Sub folder should refer to the 'inherit from parent ' in the auth method . In this case, make sure the sub folder ACCOUNT has the auth method set to 'inherit from parent'. And make sure to click the save button before exporting the collection file.